# HTML5 Audio stops before end

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

Testpage: http://fr34k.ch/public/test.html

Issue: Chrome wont send the "onended" event. Doesnt even reach the end of the mp3 file. Doesnt have to do with my coding cause its not even working if you simply open the mp3 file in the browser.
Firefox is able to send a "onended" event, but duration of song is often calculated wrong.

Is there anything what I can do to find out when the song is not playing anymore?

Problem is also posted here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=846265#c1

```js
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  
   $('#clickButton').click(function(){
    audio.src = 'http://fr34k.ch/public/Blem.mp3';
   });
   
   $('#nearEndButton').click(function(){
    audio.currentTime = audio.duration-20;
   });
   
   audio.oncanplay = function () {
    audio.play();
   }
   
   audio.onended = function(){
    alert('On Ended is called!');
   }
   
   setInterval(function(){
    var div = $('#textarea');
    div.val('CurrentTime: ' + audio.currentTime + '\nFulltime: ' + audio.duration + '\nEnded: ' + audio.ended);
   }, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id='audio'></audio>
  <button id='clickButton'>Load and Play Song</button>
  <button id='nearEndButton'>Move to end</button>
  <a href='http://fr34k.ch/public/Blem.mp3'>Open Blem.mp3</a><br>
  <textarea id='textarea' style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'></textarea>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the .mp3 file. I would start by testing with another file to see if the problem happens there too.

Comment: You should add some code to your question. We should not have to go to an external site then check the source. A JSFiddle (or equivalent) is acceptable though.

Comment: @Seblor While a Fiddle is better than nothing, it's not recommended. 3rd party links can die over time. The recommended approach is a "code snippet", right here in the question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sure, that is why I said OP "should" add some code, even though a fiddle is acceptable, or *tolerated*

Comment: @Seblor I know. My point was that you should probably be recommending code snippets, rather than Fiddles.

Comment: Éxcuse moi! Didnt know. https://jsfiddle.net/gnzrqndp/. And it doesnt really matter what type of mp3 file I take it always happen.

Comment: @Fr34k As I mentioned to Seblor, please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Please post your code, right here in your question as a "Code Snippet". I have edited your question and done that for you.

Comment: The problem is in your file. `ffmpeg -i` complains `[mp3 @ 0x7f8680002600] Skipping 437 bytes of junk at 47601.` Which makes the duration calculation base on bitrate i.e unreliable. Reencode your mp3 from a software that knows what it is doing and you should be fine.